# Shared-preference always returns default value

Tags: java, android

I've got my shared preference's setup so it uses 2 arrays. All my ListPreference works except one which uses a different android:entryValues.

I've searched high and low to try and find out how to recall android:entryValues but can't find anything specific to this problem.

When I use the key name it crashes.

Heres the code;

XML Preferences.

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="Item Size"
    android:summary="Set the item size."
    android:key="itemSize"
    android:defaultValue="Medium"
    android:entries="@array/itemSize"
    android:entryValues="@array/itemSizeNumbers"
/>
```

XML Values

```
<string-array name="itemSize">
    <item>Small</item>
    <item>Medium</item>
    <item>Large</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="itemSizeNumbers">
    <item>8</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>18</item>
</string-array>
```

The _items_screen_percentage always returns 12 no matter what.

```
this._items_screen_percentage = this.prefs.getInt("itemSizeNumbers", 12);
Log.w("Item Size",Integer.toString(this._items_screen_percentage));
```

Does anyone know of an easy way to get EntryValues from shared preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key name is `itemSize`, so you should query the preferences for `itemSize`, not `itemSizeNumbers`. Besides, it's a string array, so your result will be a string, not an integer.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for your help it was staring me in the face :-(

Comment: You query the itemSizeNumbers array with the position you get from getInt

Comment: Can you give me an example of that?